# Jasmin: MT Route to http api

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, jasmin-sms

We have an SMS Gateway works only in HTTP API with Telecom companies
Clients request SMPP Connection because their system accepts SMPP only.

Installed Jasmin SMS Gateway on DigitalOcean droplet, but Jasmin required All the MT Routes to be via SMPP Connectors only.

How can I intercept all MT Messages to be sent via HTTP API with fully status smpp response?
https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management/jcli/
The documentation doesn't mention anyways, I guess I can make it by Python but I didn't understand.

jcli : mtrouter -a
Adding a new MT Route: (ok: save, ko: exit)

> type DefaultRoute
>    arguments:
>   connector, rate
>   connector http(HTTP-01)
>   Invalid syntax for connector id, must be smppc(some_id).

Comment: Did you ever manage to succeed in the above? I have a similar situation whereby telecom company will only provide us with HTTP API so our Jasmin instance needs to send MT messages via HTTP API

Comment: We solve it via python script and success, but we didn't proceed with it